# Juju - Cant login phpmyadmin

Tags: juju, maas, phpmyadmin

I am using ubuntu 14.04.2, have juju installed in my MaaS server.
In my phpmyadmin logs:

```
2015-05-08 22:48:49 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + install_phpmyadmin
2015-05-08 22:48:49 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + [ -z  ]
2015-05-08 22:48:49 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + [ aptitude != aptitude ]
2015-05-08 22:48:49 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + [ ! -z  ]
2015-05-08 22:48:49 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + . lib/common.sh
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + set -ux
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + . /usr/share/charm-helper/sh/net.sh
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + CH_WGET_ARGS=-q --content-disposition
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + unit-get public-address
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + hostname=node3.maas
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + upstream=
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + installed=
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + [ -f .installed ]
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + cat .installed
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + installed=aptitude
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + config-get use-upstream
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + [ false = true ]
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + config
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + local override=
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + [ ! -z aptitude ]
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + [ aptitude = upstream ]
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + [ aptitude = aptitude ]
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + local load_config=aptitude
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + [ -z  ]
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + [ -z  ]
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + local load_config=aptitude
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + [ aptitude = aptitude ]
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + INSTALL_PATH=/usr/share/phpmyadmin
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + CONFIG_PATH=/etc/phpmyadmin
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + PMA_CONFIG=/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + APACHE_CONFIG=/etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + HTPASSWD_FILE=/var/www/.htpasswd
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + CREATE_SQL_FILE=/usr/share/dbconfig-common/data/phpmyadmin/install/mysql
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + config-get add-user
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + NEW_USER=juju-admin
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + config-get password
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + PASSWORD=password
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + [ ! -z juju-admin ]
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + [ ! -z password ]
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + htpasswd_add juju-admin password
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + [ ! -f /var/www/.htpasswd ]
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + juju-log Creating htpasswd file: /var/www/.htpasswd
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.juju-log cmd.go:247 Creating htpasswd file: /var/www/.htpasswd
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + htpasswd -bc /var/www/.htpasswd juju-admin password
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 /var/lib/juju/agents/unit-phpmyadmin-0/charm/hooks/config-changed: 278: /var/lib/juju/agents/unit-phpmyadmin-0/charm/hooks/config-changed: htpasswd: not found
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + chown www-data:www-data /var/www/.htpasswd
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 chown: cannot access '/var/www/.htpasswd': No such file or directory
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + juju-log Added juju-admin to /var/www/.htpasswd
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.juju-log cmd.go:247 Added juju-admin to /var/www/.htpasswd
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + config-get del-user
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + DEL_USER=
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + [ ! -z  ]
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + install_phpmyadmin
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + [ -z  ]
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + [ aptitude != aptitude ]
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + [ ! -z  ]
2015-05-08 23:04:24 INFO unit.phpmyadmin/0.config-changed logger.go:40 + chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

[image]

username: juju-admin

password: password

And can't connect. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're deploying phpmyadmin and mysql, I'm not very familiar with the phpmyadmin charm but it could be the relation hasn't been established.